# Add content in bounce margin of ScrollView in React Native?

Tags: scrollview, react-native

In my app I'm using `<ScrollView />` to view pages of a book scrolling horizontally.  When a user gets to the end of the `<ScrollView />` there is a bounce that shows a white area to the right that is only visible if the user drags the last page to the left.  I want to add some text there that says "The End" vertically.  How can I add content to the right of the `<ScrollView />` in the bounce area?

Answer (score 4):

I ALMOST figured it out.  This is close but shows up in the right side of the last page but not off the page on the right in the bounce area.  I want it to show up "to the right of the page" not "on the right side of the page."  Any other ideas?

Create a `<View style={styles.end} />` with this style:

```
theEnd: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 768, // Device height
    alignItems: 'center',
}
```

Place it right before the `<ScrollView />` and put whatever you want to show inside of the View component with the "theEnd" style.

Comment: @KyryloPolezhaiev I can't for the first 2 days.  Stackoverflow's rule, not mine.  It also turns out this isn't actually exactly what I need so I'm going to see if I get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't apply to your content, but I had the same situation except with a large image for the `ScrollView` content. I wanted both horizontal and vertical scrolling, where the edge of the image would show up only in the bounce margin. I figured out that the `scale` transformation works great for this:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}>
  <Image
    source={require('./img/map.jpg')}
    style={{transform: [{scale: 1.1}]}}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

So the image takes up 110% of the height and width of its box (which is then inside a yet smaller `ScrollView`).

EDIT: FYI, after testing, discovered this only works on iOS, not Android. (Android won't allow vertical scrolling if you set horizontal to true, and also I think it didn't render the parts outside of the normal viewing area, so the bounce margin was empty.)

Answer (score 0):

there is a prop for this called `contentContainerStyle`

```
<ScrollView 
  horizontal={true} 
  contentContainerStyle={{
    paddingLeft: 25,
    paddingRight: 25,
  }}>
 *** CONTENT ***
</ScrollView>
```